# Django Rest Framework creating Profile instance instead of updating Profile

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to update the Profile instance for a user, by sending data to the url update_profile/

I am using:

```
curl -X PUT -H "Authorization: Token sometoken" -d "name=somename&age=20&user=1" 127.0.0.1:8000/update_profile/
```

and the error I get is: {"user":["This field must be unique."]}

It seems like the error comes because the request creates a new instance of Profile, when there is already another instance of Profile with that same user. But I just want to update the current Profile instance for the user. Any idea why my code does try to create a new instance instead of updating it?

views.py

```
class UserProfileChangeAPIView(generics.UpdateAPIView, mixins.UpdateModelMixin):

    permission_classes = (
    permissions.IsAuthenticated,
    UserIsOwnerOrReadOnly,
    )
    serializer_class = UpdateProfileSerializer
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser,)

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = Profile.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
        return queryset

    def get_object(self):
        self.request.user.profile

    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.destroy(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def update(self, request, pk=None):
        try:
            self.request.user.profile

        except Http404:
            return Response(
                {'detail': 'Not found'}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        return super(UserProfileChangeAPIView, self).update(request, pk)
```

urls.py

```
     url(r'^update_profile/$', UserProfileChangeAPIView.as_view(), name='update_profile'),
```

serializers.py

```
 class UpdateProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = [
            'name',
            'age',
            'user',
        ]
```

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem like this and no need for pk in the url:

serializers.py

```
 class UpdateProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = [
            'name',
            'age',
        ]
```

views.py

```
class ProfileUpdateAPIView(UpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = UpdateProfileSerializer

    def get_object(self):
        queryset = Profile.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
        obj = queryset[0]
        return obj
```

urls.py:

```
url(r'^update/$', ProfileUpdateAPIView.as_view(), name='update'),
```

curl:

```
 curl -X PUT  -H "Authorization: Token sometoken" -d "name=newname&age=20" 127.0.0.1:8000/update/
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't include a `user` in the post data as you're already getting the profile for the current logged in user in `get_object()` and `get_queryset()`

Because the relationship between Profile and User is a `OnetoOneField`, there can't be more than one `Profile` linked to the same `User`.

I expect (from the error you've received) what's happening here is that your logged in as one `User` (e.g. id 3) and then trying to update the `Profile` to point to `User` id 1.

Comment: It seems like the id is not the reason for the problem, since it's the same user id as for the user sending the request. If I skip the user in the serializer and in the put data, this error appears: NOT NULL constraint failed: rest_auth_profile.user_id